# Associations with SOLR in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, full-text-search

I'm facing a bit of a conundrum.

I'm trying to build a search option as well as facets that will let users search by location of determined records.

The problem is that my database is structured as follows:

{Location (id, name)} has_many {User (id, name)} and user has_many {pins (id, name)}

My controller:

```
def index
    @search = Pin.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      order_by :created_at, :desc
    end
    @pins = @search.results

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pins }
    end
  end
```

My Pins Model:

```
  searchable do
    text :title, :boost => 5
    text :description
  end
    belongs_to :user
```

What can I do? Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put whatever you want in your `searchable` block like your associations and other things you need to be able to search.

```
searchable do
    text :title, :boost => 5
    text :description
    text :location do
      location.name
    end
  end
```